# Installing Xdebug for PHP on Ubuntu with XAMPP

Tags: php, xampp, xdebug, ubuntu-9.10

I'm running XAMPP 1.7.3a on Ubuntu 9.10. With Netbeans 6.7.1 as my editor, I want to be able to debug my PHP sites.

To do this, I looked up Xdebug and started following the installation instructions, found here: http://xdebug.org/docs/install.

Trying to compile the .tgz file, run in to a problem.

Step 3) I can execute that, but what use does it have? I don't get the output or what I should do with it.

Step 4) I execute the following command:

```
./configure --enable-xdebug --with-php-config=/opt/lampp/etc/
```

At the bottom of the output, it says: configure:

> error: Cannot find php-config. Please
>   use --with-php-config=PATH

I've checked the location I entered, the php.ini file is there and so are all other config files.

So, I'm not sure what to do now. Should I ignore and just do the 'make' command, or does something else yet need to be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to pass the path to the php config binary - should be something like

```
/opt/lampp/bin/php-config
```

Answer (score 0):

**All the binaries in XAMPP** are located in

```
/opt/lampp/bin
```

That's why if you work with XAMPP's PHP version you ought to proceed all operations using binaries from there.

*For example, after installation of XAMPP it's possible to set path to it's PHP bin file*.