# How do I set up PHP-debugging on Ubuntu 12.04 with Eclipse and XAMPP?

Tags: php, eclipse, debugging, ubuntu, xdebug

I've been trying to configure this for quite some time now but I can't get it running properly. Done so far:

- Downloaded the latest version of xampp and moved it to `/opt/lampp`
- Installed php5-xdebug with apt-get
- Changed implicit_flush to `On` in `/opt/lampp/etc/php.ini`
- Added the following lines to the end of the ini file:

  ```
  [xdebug]
  zend_extension="/usr/lib/php5/20090626/xdebug.so"
  xdebug.remote_enable=1
  xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
  xdebug.remote_port=9000
  xdebug.remote_host="localhost"
  ```

I've made sure to restart apache, but I still don't get an xdebug-section when showing `phpinfo();`

I think that Eclipse is configured properly, but I can't know for sure until I get xdebug to run.

Please help, all suggestions are very welcome!

**Edit:**

Here is the output of `phpinfo()`: http://www.pasteall.org/35930

**Update:**

I've downloaded Xampp 1.8.1 (I had previously xampp 1.8.0) to `/opt/lampp` and added the appropriate development files. I have both compiled Xdebug myself according to the guide at http://xdebug.org/wizard.php and installed xdebug through `/opt/lampp/bin/pecl`.

Now my php.ini looks like this:

```
zend_extension = "/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_host = "localhost"
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
```

I don't know what to do, http://xdebug.org/wizard.php still reports that Xdebug isn't installed. Could it be a permission issue? Currently the permissions for the extensions are as follows:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 niklas niklas  88376 Sep 30 10:43 interbase.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 niklas niklas 184920 Sep 30 10:43 oci8.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 niklas niklas 118592 Sep 30 10:43 pgsql.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 niklas niklas 830886 Oct 10 15:10 xdebug.so
```

Should they be owned by someone else? Must I enable any additional options in php.ini? This is my current output of `phpinfo()`: http://www.pasteall.org/36135

Comment: Can you paste your full output from `phpinfo` somewhere

Comment: I've linked the full output in the "edit"-section of the question. Thanks for taking a shot at this!

Comment: Can you not just use `apt-get` to install what you need rather than using xampp?

Comment: I prefer the ease of use of working with xampp when I'm in a development environment - like being able to utilize the built in GUI-control panel. From what I've gathered the issues I'm experiencing when setting up xdebug with xampp isn't the norm.

Comment: I have always used xampp on windows, and its been fine. But for linux I used `apt-get`, sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: did you restart Apache after changing php configuration?

Comment: Yep, I decided to just go with a regular lampp-installation instead and disable auto-starting if the services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no sign of why it isn't working I've given up on xampp and just installed a regular lamp-server with xdebug through `apt-get`. I disabled mysql and apache2 from starting during boot so that they are not running if I don't want them. Here is a very simple tutorial on how to enable xdebug-debugging with Eclipse: http://www.web-brainz.co.uk/Xdebug

The other answers will surely be the most fitting for other users though they unfortunately didn't fix my issue. Thank you very much for help!

Answer (score 1):

### Tailored Installation Instructions

### Summary

**Xdebug installed:** no

**Server API:** Apache 2.0 Handler

**Windows:** no

**Zend Server:** no

**PHP Version:** 5.4.4

**Zend API nr:** 220100525

**PHP API nr:** 20100525

**Debug Build:** no

**Thread Safe Build:** no

**Configuration File Path:** /opt/lampp/etc

**Configuration File:** /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini

**Extensions directory:** /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525

### Instructions

1. Download [xdebug-2.2.1.tgz](http://xdebug.org/files/xdebug-2.2.1.tgz)
2. Unpack the downloaded file with `tar -xvzf xdebug-2.2.1.tgz`
3. Run: `cd xdebug-2.2.1`
4. Run: `phpize`

   As part of its output it should show:

   ```
   Configuring for:
   ...
   Zend Module Api No:      20100525
   Zend Extension Api No:   220100525
   ```

   If it does not, you are using the wrong `phpize`. Please follow
   [this FAQ entry](http://xdebug.org/docs/faq#custom-phpize) and skip the next step.
5. Run: `./configure`
6. Run: `make`
7. Run: `cp modules/xdebug.so /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525`
8. Edit `/opt/lampp/etc/php.ini` and add the line
   `zend_extension = /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/xdebug.so`
9. Restart the webserver

http://xdebug.org/wizard.php

Comment: I've followed the guide but the wizard over at http://xdebug.org/wizard.php still says that it isn't installed :/

Comment: Please take a look at the update to my question to see if you know what the problem is :)

Comment: Have you tried telling configure where your lamp is as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168411/installing-xdebug-for-php-on-ubuntu-with-xampp

`./configure --enable-xdebug --with-php-config=/opt/lampp/bin/php-config`

Though it really is trivial to set up a LAMP stack on Ubuntu with `tasksel`: http://www.unixmen.com/install-lamp-with-1-command-in-ubuntu-1010-maverick-meerkat/

Answer (score 1):

See below URL i think it is very help full to you

http://www.edmondscommerce.co.uk/ubuntu/ubuntu-xampp-xdebug-install/

http://www.webhelp2u.com/article/install-xdebug-on-lampp

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9640912/problems-setting-up-eclipse-with-xdebug

**Read it:-**

**Install XDebug on ( LAMPP OR XAMPP For Linux )**

http://www.edmondscommerce.co.uk/ubuntu/ubuntu-xampp-xdebug-install/

http://www.webhelp2u.com/article/install-xdebug-on-lampp

To Install XDebug on LAMPP

1. Download the latest version of ( XAMPP For Linux ) From site http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-linux.html
2. Install it. To install lampp, extract and put in /opt directory.
3. Download Development package from same site.
4. Extract it, copy and paste "include" folder from Development package to /opt/lampp directory. ( This package would use for compiling XDebug source )
5. Run command /opt/lampp/bin/pecl update-channels. this would update the pecl channels database at your local pc.
6. Run command /opt/lampp/bin/pecl install Xdebug. And wait for finishing the process.
7. Now xdebug.so file has been created in /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/ directory.
8. Now Open the file php.ini and add the line zend_extension="/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/path_to_xdebug.so". at the end of file.
9. Restart Lampp & Check enabled or not using phpinfo();

**Update my answer after your comment**

See below URL i think it is very help full to you.

**Setup Xdebug for PHP5 in Ubuntu**

http://gayanhewa.info/setup-xdebug-php5-ubuntu/

Comment: I've followed the guide but the wizard over at http://xdebug.org/wizard.php still says that it isn't installed :/

Comment: Please take a look at the update to my question to see if you know what the problem is :)

Comment: See below url i think it is very help full to you. http://www.edmondscommerce.co.uk/ubuntu/ubuntu-xampp-xdebug-install/

Comment: I've already read the pages you've linked in your answer, they describe the exact same procedure as you did and it doesn't work. Refer to the "Update"-section of my question to see what I've attempted to fix the issue.

Comment: Are you kidding me? You have just copied the answer from another question which is totally irrelevant to my issue!

Answer (score 0):

- On a fresh ubuntu 12.04 run:

> apt-get install php5-xdebug

- Check for xdebug if it is installed:

> php --version

it looks like this:

root@ubuntu-SandBox:/var/www# php --version
PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.19 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Jul  2 2015 15:05:04)
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.1.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2010, by Derick Rethans
root@ubuntu-SandBox:/var/www#

- Modify your php.ini to load Xdebug run:

> vi /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

and add at the bottom of the file:

[xdebug]

xdebug.remote_enable=1

xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"

xdebug.remote_port=9000

/* this is the ip address of your PHPstorm IDE machine. */

xdebug.remote_host="10.70.111.11"

- Restart your server:

> service apache2 restart

- Now your server is ready for your client IDE machine to connect.
- Here is how to configure PHPSTORM:

Follow this instruction of JetBrain https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Validating+Your+Debugging+Configuration

or

On menu Run => Web Server Debug Validation and you will see something like this:

[image]

- If you dont get the yellow and everything is blue you are good!
- Install chrome extension xdebug helper from here:

> https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xdebug-helper/eadndfjplgieldjbigjakmdgkmoaaaoc?hl=en

- Start a debug session in browser by enable this extension by click on it and the bug icon turns green.
- Then in IDE Run => Listening for php debug connections.
- Set a breakpoint in the source code
- Load your php page (webapp) and it will be stopped at breakpoints.

Done.